# Compare 2 columns in Pandas DataFrame with .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare two columns with value (1) and list rows that satisfy this condition. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[0,1,1,0,1],
                   'col2':[0,1,0,1,0],
                   'ord':[0,1,2,3,4]
})

df1 = df.loc[df['col'] == 1 & df['col2'] == 1]

print(df1)
```

Expected output:

```
   col  col2  ord
0    1     1    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parentheses because priority precedence of `&` operator:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['col'] == 1) & (df['col2'] == 1)]
```